# Extend/renew a p12 certificate self signed expired

Tags: flash, ssl, openssl, adobe, ssl-certificate

Our adobe air application p12 certificate is already expired.

Are there any ways to renew to same certificate without having to create another one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A renewed certificate is nothing else then using the same Certificate Signing Request, which includes the Subject information and the public key, and sign it again by the Certificate Agency (in this case you again because it is self-signed), although with a changed expire time.

So, extending a certificate will create a a new one, although with mostly the same information in it. There is no way to somehow make an existing certificate last longer, because the expiration time is inside the certificate and included in the signature. Changing the time inside an existing certificate would make the signature and thus the certificate invalid.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot renew or modify the contents of a certificate once it is issued by a certification authority (CA).

You will have to submit the **Certificate Signing Request** (CSR) again and must be issued by the CA and must be replaced on the server or the application.

Comment: So technically can u extended the expiration date at the time of creating a new CSR or requesting a CRS from certificate authority ???